# How to display column name in jquery table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I want to display my data from *SQLite* in jquery table. When I run the app in my mobile, it only shows my data from *SQLite*. The column name is not showing.  How can I display the column name?

table in **html**

```
     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <table data-role="table" id="mytable" data-mode="reflow">
            <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>event</th>
              <th>location</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="abc"></tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
function view() { 
if (db==null) {
    alert('Error: Database is null.');
    return;
}

db.executeSql(
    'SELECT `id`, `data`, `data2` FROM `info` ORDER BY `data` ASC',
    [],
    function(resultset) { 
        var length = resultset.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            $('#abc').append('<tr><th>'+resultset.rows.item(i).id+'</th>','<td>'+resultset.rows.item(i).data+'</td>','<td>'+resultset.rows.item(i).data2+'</td></tr>');
        }
        //$("#listData").listview( "refresh" );
    },
    function(error) { 
        alert('Error: '+error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: An advice, you should concat all your rows in one string and append it once.

Comment: sorry I dont get it...how can I do ?

Comment: In short, ex: var rows = ''; for(...){ rows = rows + '<tr>.........</tr>';} $('#abc').append(rows);

Answer (score 0):

You have TH tag in your rows, try to use only TD in your TBODY.

**EDIT:**

Have you look at the CSS?

Comment: I changed the tag to TD...still same result

Comment: @jdk have you look at the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  tag on the appended row.

```
db.executeSql(
'SELECT `id`, `data`, `data2` FROM `info` ORDER BY `data` ASC',
[],
function(resultset) { 
    var length = resultset.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        $('#abc').append('<tr><td>'+resultset.rows.item(i).id+'</td>','<td>'+resultset.rows.item(i).data+'</td>','<td>'+resultset.rows.item(i).data2+'</td></tr>');
    }
    //$("#listData").listview( "refresh" );
},
function(error) { 
    alert('Error: '+error.message);
}
```

);

Comment: I have changed the <th> tag to <td>...still same result. Only data, no column name